# What is the total area enclosed by a polar curve and the x-axis?

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am aware of the formula.. but can someone give me a clear definition of what the total area enclosed by a polar curve represents.
Thanks

Comment: Draw the polar curve on the plane; see the part of it that is "inside"; that's what the "area enclosed by the polar curve" is.

Comment: Why does the title say "total area enclosed by a polar curve and the x-axis" and the question "total area enclosed by a polar curve"? Those are two different things.

Comment: If you put together the comments from Arturo and joriki I think you have an answer.  If the question is the title and the curve is $r=1$, take the part of the area where $\cos(\theta)\ge 1$.  I share their frustration with the conflict.